# Allow the use of files directive in .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

In my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` I have the following config:

```
...
<Directory /var/www>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>
...
```

And in `/var/www/.htaccess`

```
...
<files .htaccess>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</files>
...
```

But I get an error:

```
[Sat Mar 22 00:00:00.020630 2014] [core:alert] [pid 1234] [client 285.123.123.123:1234] /var/www/.htaccess: order not allowed here
```

When I change `AllowOverride FileInfo` to `AllowOverride All` the error is gone.

Should I do it differently?
Is there an other option to enable files directive?

I use `Apache 2.4.6`

Answer (score 2):

Order/Deny/Allow implies `Limit`, not `FileInfo`, as value of `AllowOverride`.

Also note that these directives are deprecated since Apache 2.4.0: they are replaced by `Require`.